# how to send form values to php using AJAX without reloading page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I have this AJAX function which starts PHP function in server without reloading page and sends back generated info, but I also need to send a form input values to that PHP script how do I do that?

AJAX:

```
    function sorting() 
{

  var ajax = getRequest();
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
      if(ajax.readyState == 4)
      {
          document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
      }

  }
  document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = "<br/><img src=img/ajax-loader.gif><br/><br/>";
  ajax.open("POST", "sorting.php", true);
  ajax.send(null);
}
```

Truncated HTML form:

```
 <form method="post"  action="" name="dateform" id="dateform">

<select name="n_metai" id="n_metai" ><option value="1">1</option>... 
</select>   

<select name="n_menuo" id="n_menuo" ><option value="2">2</option>... 
</select> 

<input type="text" name="skaitliukas" id="skaitliukas" size="3" value="1" title="Mažiausias skambučių pasikartojimas">

<input type="checkbox" name="nuliniai" id="nuliniai"   value="1" title="Rodyti tik su nulinėmis trukmėmis">

<button name="submit_button" onclick='sorting(); return false;'> Pateikti</button>
</form>
```

Comment: your put the form body in your send method. `ajax.send("txt1=text2");`

Comment: What exactly does txt1 and text2 mean ?

Comment: @user2630991: `txt1=txt2` => `name_of_post_param=value_of_post_param`, so if you were to pass `'txt1=txt2'` to the `send` call, server-side you would be able to do `$_POST['txt1'] === 'txt2'`, and it'd evaluate to true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
ajax.send(null);
```

If you were to send a `GET` request, then you pass nothing (or null) to the `send` call, but you're `POST`-ing data, so you'll have to pass the data through there.
A basic way to do that, would be this:

```
var frm = document.getElementById('dateform'),
data = [];//empty array
for (var i=0;i<frm.elements.length;i++)
{
    data.push(frm.elements[i].name + '=' + frm.elements[i].value);
}
ajax.send(data.join('&'));
```

Comment: And how do I do that ? what names do I use ?

Comment: @user2630991: Added basic example, you can use (part of) [google's `serialize` function](https://code.google.com/p/form-serialize/source/browse/trunk/serialize-0.2.js) if your form is more complex, and requires you to do so

Comment: And if I were to use GET method what would change ?

Comment: Using `Get`, you'd have to change `ajax.open("POST", "sorting.php", true); ajax.send('your=data&goes=here');` to `ajax.open("GET", "sorting.php?your=data&goes=here", true); ajax.send(null);`

Comment: It works now I changed it to GET method and generated url(sorting.php?your=data&goes=here) with serialize function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2630991: Do consider giving `POST` another go, just use `ajax.open('POST', 'sorting.php', true);` and send the data like so `ajax.send(serialize(document.getElementById('dateform'));`, I see no reason why that wouldn't work either

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery for that.

```
$.ajax({
type: "post", //methos
url: "yourpage.php", //where to post
data: { //parameters
    n_metai: $('select[name="n_metai"] option:selected').val(), 
    skaitliukas: $('#skaitliukas').val()
    //etc...
}
}).done(function(msg) {
    alert( "Done: " + msg ); //display message box with replay
});
```

Comment: IF there's no jQuery tag, then don't assume jQuery... the tag-wiki's are quite clear on that

Comment: But that would reload the page after submiting the form ?

Comment: @user2630991: It wouldn't, `$.ajax` is just jQ for `xhr.send()`. classically, you'd implement this call in an event handler, that fires on the submit event of the form, and then `return false;`, which is the same as calling `e.preventDefault` _and_ `e.stopPropagation` _in jQuery_, in vanillaJS, returning false doesn't stop the event from propagating/bubbling

Comment: **Elias Van Ootegem**, and what about the situation when the one who asked a question not knowing about such a library?

Comment: @YuraSokolov: Then you can _suggest_ a lib in a comment or answer, but that answer must conform to the tag description of JavaScript: _"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected"_. If you had more rep, I'd probably down-vote this answer, but since you're not a long-standing member, I thought I'd simply point out what you ought to keep in mind...